How do I set my flex correctly on this sign up page
I am currently working on project #6 of the Odin Project and having some minor problems. I am trying to get my project as close to https://cdn.statically.io/gh/TheOdinProject/curriculum/5f37d43908ef92499e95a9b90fc3cc291a95014c/html_css/project-sign-up-form/sign-up-form.png that^ as possible within reason. So I am currently trying to set the right flex or flex-shorthand rules in CSS to move the input fields so that I get two columns of bars instead of one but don't know how.
I tried different types of positioning, input:nth-child(even), and some other things that still didn't work for some reason. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/El0din-Ruh/pen/gONayLX


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    <style>
         body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;

         }
         @font-face {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
            src: url(Norse-Bold.otf);
         }
         html {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
         }
         #Right-side {
            padding-left: 20px;
         }
         p {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
         }
         form {
            background-color:burlywood;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            position:static;

         }
         form div input {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            position:relative;
         }
         input:nth-of-type(2), input:nth-of-type(4), input:nth-of-type(6){
            color:aqua;
         }
        

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="Tree.jpg" height ="600px"
        width="300px">
    </div>
    <div id="Right-side">
        <p>
            Attention! This is not a real online service! But please, still sign up for its' makers benefit. 
            You can sign up right below: Right... Down... There.
        </p>

        <p>I for one very much think that you should sign up OR login</p>
    <form id="Inputs">
        <div id="FN">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        </div>
        <div id="LN">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
        </div>    
        <div id="EM">
            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div id="PN">
            <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="number" name="phone_number" id="phone_number">
        </div>
        <div id="PS">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>    
        <div id="CFNPS">
            <label for="CPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="CPassword" id="ConPassword">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Create an Account</button>
    </form>
    <div id="Login">
        <p>Already have an Account? <a href="https://google.com">Log In</href></p>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>




I think you would need to group up inputs by wrapping them in a div or similar, then apply flex to that wrapper.

Could you edit my code and show me? I thought I already had enough containers. Not sure why form div input isn't good enough outside of form.

Currently "flex-direction: column;" on your form is making all the divs in the form element stack vertically in a column. A quick fix could be to remove that so the divs are positioned horizontally, use flex-wrap to make them break onto a new line and then set the width of each div to 50% so that you get 2 divs to each row. The 50% width is set with the "flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);" which is 50%, less the 5px of padding that is on each side of the div. Something like the below snippet.
Note, I added a container div to the content so that it stacks your form and image on small screens - otherwise you don't have enough room and the form will break.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
            align-items: center;
            max-width: 1280px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .container {
                flex-direction: row;
            }
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
            src: url(Norse-Bold.otf);
        }

        html {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
        }

        #Right-side {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        p {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        form {
            background-color: burlywood;
            display: flex;
            /* flex-direction: column; 
                justify-content: center;
                position:static; */
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        form div {
            flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        form div input {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        input:nth-of-type(2),
        input:nth-of-type(4),
        input:nth-of-type(6) {
            color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="image">
            <img src="Tree.jpg" height="600px" width="300px">
        </div>
        <div id="Right-side">
            <p>
                Attention! This is not a real online service! But please, still sign up for its' makers benefit.
                You can sign up right below: Right... Down... There.
            </p>

            <p>I for one very much think that you should sign up OR login</p>
            <form id="Inputs">
                <div id="FN">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                </div>
                <div id="LN">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                </div>
                <div id="EM">
                    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div id="PN">
                    <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone_number" id="phone_number">
                </div>
                <div id="PS">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <div id="CFNPS">
                    <label for="CPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="CPassword" id="ConPassword">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Create an Account</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="Login">
                <p>Already have an Account? <a href="https://google.com">Log In</href>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>




The HTML and CSS requires a little restructuring to create a two-column layout for your input fields, as below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;

        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
            src: url(Norse-Bold.otf);
        }
        html {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
        }
        #Right-side {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        p {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        form {
            background-color: burlywood;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            gap: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .form-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            gap: 20px;
        }
        .form-row > div {
            flex: 1;
        }
        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        button {
            align-self: flex-start;
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
        input:nth-of-type(2), input:nth-of-type(4), input:nth-of-type(6){
            color:aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="Tree.jpg" height ="600px"
             width="300px">
    </div>
    <div id="Right-side">
        <p>
            Attention! This is not a real online service! But please, still sign up for its' makers benefit.
            You can sign up right below: Right... Down... There.
        </p>
        <p>I for one very much think that you should sign up OR login</p>
        <form id="Inputs">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div id="FN">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                </div>
                <div id="LN">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div id="EM">
                    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div id="PN">
                    <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone_number" id="phone_number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div id="PS">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <div id="CFNPS">
                    <label for="CPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="CPassword" id="ConPassword">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Create an Account</button>
        </form>
        <div id="Login">
            <p>Already have an Account? <a href="https://google.com">Log In</href></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

You have a few other issues with your code, however, this should address your immediate issue.

Thanks very much for the help! What other issues are there with my code?

Just wrap the labels and inputs in the one div as per your pen the code will be like this.


.flex-sec {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    <style>
         body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;

         }
         @font-face {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
            src: url(Norse-Bold.otf);
         }
         html {
            font-family: Norse-Bold;
         }
         #Right-side {
            padding-left: 20px;
         }
         p {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
         }
         form {
            padding: 30px;
            background-color:burlywood;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            align-items: center;

         }
         form div input {
            display: flex;

            flex-wrap: wrap;
         }

         form div input:nth-of-type(2n){
            align-self: flex-end
         }
         form div input:nth-of-type(2n-1){
            align-self: flex-start
         }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="Tree.jpg" height ="600px"
        width="300px">
    </div>
    <div id="Right-side">
        <p>
            Attention! This is not a real online service! But please, still sign up for its' makers benefit. 
            You can sign up right below: Right... Down... There.
        </p>

        <p>I for one very much think that you should sign up OR login</p>
    <form id="Inputs">
      <div class="flex-sec">
        <div id="FN">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        </div>
        <div id="LN">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-sec">
        <div id="EM">
            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div id="PN">
            <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="number" name="phone_number" id="phone_number">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-sec">
        <div id="PS">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>    
        <div id="CFNPS">
            <label for="CPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="CPassword" id="ConPassword">
        </div>
      </div>
        <button type="submit">Create an Account</button>
    </form>
    <div id="Login">
        <p>Already have an Account? <a href="https://google.com">Log In</href></p>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



